# revealing module pattern inner outer variable mismatch

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

```html
<html><body><button>setSpeed</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    _.setSpeed();
    console.log('_.slow: ' + _.slow);
  });
});

var _ = (function(){
  var slow = 4;
  
  function setSpeed(){ 
    if (slow == 4) {
      slow = 1;
    } else if (slow == 1){
      slow = 16;
    } else {
      slow = 4;
    }
    console.log('slow: '+ slow);
  }
  return { slow: slow, setSpeed: setSpeed };

})();

</script></body></html>
```

I don't understand why the console.log for slow and _.slow don't match? What am I missing?

By returning both the var slow and function setSpeed in the IIEF, I would think they should match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
return { slow: slow, setSpeed: setSpeed };
```

You are creating a new object with two properties, `slow` and `setSpeed`.  The value for `slow` is assigned from the `var slow`.  Since that is a primitive type (not a reference value) you're getting a copy of the current value of slow (4).

When you call setSpeed, it modifies the `var slow` changing it to 1.  This does not affect `_.slow` (since it's not a reference).

Comment: You can try to add a getter function for slow if you want to check the value of slow inside yout IIEF.

`function getSlow(){ 
    return slow;
}`

in your `return` part `return { getSlow: getSlow, setSpeed: setSpeed };`

or you can bind a getter function for your `slow` property. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)